# when adding CFNotificationCenter observer is NULL, how about removing

Tags: ios, core-foundation

So on iOS platform, I see multiple examples about `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver` that taking `observer` argument as NULL, such as

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center, NULL, notificationCallback, 
                                    CFSTR("MyNotification"), NULL, 
                                    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

and the doc said

> observer
>
> The observer. In macOS 10.3 and later, this parameter may be NULL.

However, in `CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver()` or `CFNotificationCenterRemoveEveryObserver()`, it's said

> observer
>
> The observer. This value must not be NULL.

So it's a little confused to me, that if my observer is NULL, should I call `CFNotificationCenterRemoveEveryObserver()` in my dealloc method? If so, what I should I pass for observer, still NULL?